# formula for Indexing

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

i have values in my sheet
5251, 3520, 2532,17
and
in another sheet have index like

0-500
501-1000
1001-1500
1501-2500
2501-5000
5001-10000

i want appropriate index Infront of my value

need formula in excel for

Value | Required Ans |

5251    |      5001-10000 |

3520    |     2501-5000 |

2532 | 2501-5000 |

17 | 0-500 |

same value could be anything

Comment: finally i got solution  Minifs() -----  index  Sheet12!A:A ,   max range  Sheet12!B:B, lookup value ">"&H4  and vlookup  ---------      formula is  =vlookup(MINIFS(Sheet12!A:A,Sheet12!B:B,">"&H4),Sheet12!A:C,3,0)

Answer (score 1):

So like this:

[image]

Not used your data but you should see how it goes, other options exist like lookup() and xlookup() depending on your version of excel.

In googlesheets you will need to check the functions and arguments match but if not the help will explain the differences.

Comment: I have value like 5251 in separate sheet  and have matrix  like 0-500 , 501-1000,1001-6000 in another sheet ,,, then answer should  come in my sheet  1001-6000 in front of 5251

Comment: Then use the index() with match(), index() can be on sheet 1 and match() on sheet 2, the ONLY important bit is they must have the same number of items.

Comment: How it will be determine if all values between 1001 and 6000 have been answered as '1001-6000' and so forth? & how catch the upper and lower?   & the number could be anything.

Comment: Build what I have shown and test.